# JQuery add class to Parent <li> of <a> with href

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, parent, addclass

So i have this code

```
<li>
<a href="./home.php"></a>
</li>
```

I want to add class active to `<li>`

But i want to add this class by selecting `<a>` with `href ="./home.php"` get to it's parent `<li>` and add class active.

The final code will look like this

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="./home.php"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: What about `$('a[href="./home.php"]').parent().addClass('active')`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/764/)

`$('a[href="./home.php"]').parent('li').addClass('active');`